# How to get value of cell and insert it to entry?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want some code to be like:

1. Push button,
2. Then click on some cell,
3. And get its value to Entry:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

...

```
self.content.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.get_values)

def get_values(self):
    self.content.tableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.eject_values)

def eject_values(self,row,col):
    a = self.content.tableWidget.item(row, col).text()
    self.content.lineEdit.setText(a)
    self.content.tableWidget.cellClicked.disconnect()
```

...